# How to use query for Oracle pivot?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I have four columns like below.

[image]

Will I be able to get something like this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Well... you could try. There is an excellent article on pivot by Chris Saxon: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot . Have a look at that and see if that works for your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation. It is a database-independent syntax, which is more flexible than Oracle-specific `pivot` syntax:

```
select
    piece_id,
    max(case when attrb_code = 'A' then attrb_a_value end) a,
    max(case when attrb_code = 'B' then attrb_a_value end) b,
    max(case when attrb_code = 'C' then attrb_a_value end) c,
    max(case when attrb_code = 'D' then attrb_b_value end) d
from mytable
group by piece_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COALESCE` (or `NVL`) in the `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX( COALESCE( attrb_a_value, attrb_b_value ) )
  FOR attrb_code IN (
    'A' AS A,
    'B' AS B,
    'C' AS C,
    'D' AS D
  )
)
```

So, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( piece_id, attrb_code, attrb_a_value, attrb_b_value ) AS
SELECT 22333, 'A', 8, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22333, 'B', 9, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22333, 'C', 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22333, 'D', NULL, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22332, 'A', 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22332, 'B', 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22332, 'C', 7, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22332, 'D', NULL, 5 FROM DUAL
```

This outputs:

> ```
> PIECE_ID |  A |  B |  C |  D
> -------: | -: | -: | -: | -:
>    22333 |  8 |  9 |  4 |  5
>    22332 |  2 |  3 |  7 |  5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc1de451e3a58490b74b03633126c446)*